# multiline feature or wrap text feature in jface tableviewer

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

i have a jface tableviewer table where in the data in the columns just come in one single line even if it is the long text. I would want a wrap text feature or a multiple line feature for table, if text exceeding a certain limit. Could anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 5):

See this SWT snippet [draw multiple lines of text in a table item](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet231.java) and this JFace [SnippetSnippet006TableMultiLineCells](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets#Snippet006TableMultiLineCells)

Comment: the second link is dead

Comment: @Tonny Madsen corrected link. Check you mean the same?