# Unable to wrap text within JFace TableViewerColumn

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer

I am unable to wrap the text within a table cell when the width exceeds a specified limit.

Code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<TableData> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<TableData>());
    list.add(new TableData("Jack Hodgins", 24) );
    list.add(new TableData("This is just aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            + "\n" + "hugeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
            + "\n" + "messsageeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
            + "\n" + "to checkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"
            + "\n" + "wrap functionalityyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", 50));

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setText("Table Viewer Column");
    shell.setSize(800, 1500);

    TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.FILL | SWT.MULTI |  SWT.H_SCROLL |  SWT.V_SCROLL |  SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

    Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setSize(1000, 1500);
    table.setLayout(new TableLayout());

    /** Column for Name */
    TableViewerColumn columnName = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP);
    columnName.getColumn().setWidth(250);       
    columnName.getColumn().setText("Name");
    columnName.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell)
        {
            Object element = cell.getElement();
            if (element instanceof TableData)
            {
                TableData obj = (TableData) element;
                cell.setText(obj.getName());

            }
        }
    });

    /** Column for Age */
    TableViewerColumn columnAge = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
    columnAge.getColumn().setWidth(100);    
    columnAge.getColumn().setText("Age");
    columnAge.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell)
        {
            Object element = cell.getElement();
            if (element instanceof TableData)
            {
                TableData obj = (TableData) element;
                cell.setText(String.valueOf(obj.getAge()) );

            }
        }
    });

    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setInput(list);
    viewer.refresh();

    table.pack();
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.setVisible(true);
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();

}

public static class TableData
{
    String name;
    int age;

    public TableData(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}



}
```

I will know the width of my table cell, and if the text exceeds that limit I want the remaining text to be in a new line.

I have looked at other links from stackoverflow -

[multiline feature or wrap text feature in jface tableviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355693/multiline-feature-or-wrap-text-feature-in-jface-tableviewer)
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet231.java
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet006TableMultiLineCells.java

Still unable to find a solution to this.
Kindly help.

Comment: You could use `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` but this means drawing the cells yourself. However Table always shows all rows with the same height so all the rows will have the height of the multiline row.

Comment: Hi greg.. So is it not possible that the cell height is increased in the table only when text size is more and for the others it remains as a singleline row?
Also can you please explain how to use OwnerDrawLabelProvider. I tried setting the LabelProvider as OwnerDrawLabelProvider and couldn't get the functionality required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This owner draw label provider set as the label provider for `columnName` shows multiple lines split at the newlines. But all rows have the size of the deepest row.

```java
  private static class NameLabelProvider extends OwnerDrawLabelProvider
  {
    private static final int TEXT_MARGIN = 3;

    @Override
    protected void erase(final Event event, final Object element)
    {
      event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
    }

    @Override
    protected void measure(final Event event, final Object element)
    {
      final TableData data = (TableData)element;
      final String text = data.getName();
      final Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
      event.width = size.x + 2 * TEXT_MARGIN;
      event.height = Math.max(event.height, size.y + TEXT_MARGIN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paint(final Event event, final Object element)
    {
      final TableData data = (TableData)element;
      final String text = data.getName();
      event.gc.drawText(text, event.x + TEXT_MARGIN, event.y, true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks greg. Able to add multiline feature now. Just a question.. Is there any framework that I could use to create table which would provide automatic text wrapping dynamically based on table cell width and also only based on need will increase the size not for all the rows ?

Comment: I have never really looked for one as I don't need this. In principle it could be written in SWT, but different row heights make everything more complex.